# multiple join 4 table in database

Tags: mysql

can help me, what kind of query is used?

I tried with query join still fail because in `'table company'` have id_contract
and I need to get data from `'table contract'`

but I got an error like

> "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, bool given in"

```
 $data = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * 
                                    FROM location
                                    inner join employee 
                                        on `employee`.`id_employee` = location.`id_employee`
                                    inner join company 
                                        on `company`.`id_company` =  location.`id_company`
                                    inner join contract 
                                        on `contract`.`id_contract` =  company .`id_contract`");
```

```
table 1 : location
| id_location | id_employee | id_company

table 2 : employee
| id_employee | name | description

table 3 : company
| id_company | id_contract | company_name

table 4 : contract
| id_contract | first_date | end_date
```

can i get all data from each table ?

Comment: `SELECT contract.*`?  Can you add sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my query is failed, massege error like "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in "

Comment: Your query fails for some reason, so you receive `bool` (`false`) instead of results. That's why you get that warning later when you execute `mysqli_fetch_array`. To check what's wrong with your query, run it directly in some MySQL client (like phpmyadmin, etc.) or use `mysqli_error` function to get last error in PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

This query return all columns from all joined table:

```
"SELECT loc.*,emp.*,cmp.*,cnt.*
                                FROM location loc
                                inner join employee emp
                                    on `employee`.`id_employee` = location.`id_employee`
                                inner join company cmp
                                    on `company`.`id_company` =  location.`id_company`
                                inner join contract cnt
                                    on `contract`.`id_contract` =  company .`id_contract`");
```